# Specify an attribute or mention table name for last in Model.last(5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In an active-record chaining association when using last(10), am getting an error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: Mysql2::Error: Column 'id'
>   in order clause is ambiguous

To solve this we normally specify the table name i.e posts.id, but how can i put the same logic with last?

After going through the documentation of [ActiveRecord Last](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last), found it uses the primary key. Also can we specify a custom attribute?

Any help or thoughts appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think `Model.order('models.id DESC').last(5)` can do it. You can make a default scope where the order is defined, then you would not need to call `.order('models.id DESC')` every time

Comment: yes thats the alternative, but cant we do with last?

Comment: According to this source code : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/da5e5c5f779355a2e99e63a90612cbeaeb0fc986/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L134 : you should be able to pass argument(s) as a regular `.find()`, this should work: `Model.last(5, :order => 'models.id DESC')` (can't test it now, try this and tell me about it)

Comment: thanks @MrYoshiji it does work alternately. i would write down an answer just to add reference for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks MrYoshji for his suggestions, the last for the activerecord works alternately.

You can pass the **limit** or **a specific column**, but not both.

It accepts only attribute, if of type integer it uses limit, as per documentation

```
order("#{primary_key} DESC").limit(*args).reverse
```

for specifying an attribute other than "id" we can use this:

Model.last(:order => 'models.score')

As my requirements goes it shud be

> order("models.id desc").limit(12)

Let me know if this can be made better.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error means you're ordering by a column called `id` and that you've at least two tables in your `from` and `join` clauses which contain a column with that name. You need to qualify it accordingly, e.g. `yourtable.id`.

Comment: Thanks Denis, i understand the error, question am asking is how do i qualify mytable.id when using last ?

Comment: You'd want to specify an explicit sort order, using `yourtable.id` instead of `id`, and apply a limit accordingly.